# Controller as a Service in an Application  " Call to a member function has() on a non-object" 

Tags: php, web-applications, symfony, controller, bundle

I'm doing my first WebSocket Application in Symfony user Varspool/WebsocketBundle.
I need to insert data for a vote server side.
To do so, I've made an Controller that insert data in the DB when the user chose an answer for the vote.

Following this documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/controller/service.html I've got a "Call to undefined method forward()" error. It should be because I'm in an Application and not in a Controller

I see a lot of things like rebooting the Kernel inside the Controller and a lot of lot of other strange things like this :

```
$kernel = new \AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel->boot();
$controller->setContainer($kernel->getContainer());
```

**[EDIT]**
I show you my last try that display a **" Call to a member function has() on a non-object"** (which I don't really understand oO)

**My Controller as service**

**Edit1 - Update __construct**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Krum\AGBundle\Application\ExempleApplication;
use Krum\AGBundle\Form\AGVoteSetType;
use Krum\AGBundle\Form\AGVoteAffichType;
use Krum\AGBundle\Form\AGVoteType;
use Krum\AGBundle\Entity\AGDummy;
use Krum\AGBundle\Entity\AGVote;
use Krum\AGBundle\Entity\AGReponse;
use Krum\AGBundle\Entity\AGScrutin;
use Krum\KBundle\Entity\Users;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;


class AGServicesController extends Controller {

    protected $em;    

    public function __construct($entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }




    public function get($service){           
        return $this->container->get($service);
    }

   public function voteeffective($vote, $reponse, $users) {
       $em = $this->em;
       $userbyFOS = $em->createQueryBuilder('u')
              ->select('u')
              ->from('KrumKBundle:Users', 'u')
              ->leftJoin('u.utilisateur', 'ut')
              ->where('ut.id = ?1')
              ->setParameter(1, $users)
              ->getQuery();
      $user = $userbyFOS->getOneOrNullResult();      
      $userstatus = $em->createQueryBuilder('scru')
              ->select('scru')
              ->from('KrumAGBundle:AGScrutin', 'scru')
              ->where('scru.users = ?1')
              ->andWhere('scru.AGVote = ?2')
              ->andWhere('scru.AGReponse = ?3')
              ->setParameters(array(
                      1 => $user,
                      2 => $vote,
                      3 => $reponse
                      ))
              ->getQuery();
       $stat = $userstatus->getResult();

      if ($stat == NULL) {
         $votety = $em->getRepository('KrumAGBundle:AGVote')->findOneById($vote);
         $reponsety = $em->getRepository('KrumAGBundle:AGReponse')->findOneById($reponse);

         $scrutinty = new AGScrutin();
         $scrutinty->setAGReponse($reponsety);
         $scrutinty->setAGVote($votety);
         $scrutinty->setUsers($user);
         $scrutinty->setType("AGScrutin");
         $em->persist($scrutinty);
         $em->flush();

         return "vote-ok:".$scrutinty->getId();
      } else {
         return "vote-false";
      }
    }  

}
```

**My Application (WebSocket Server)**

```
namespace Krum\AGBundle\Application;

use Varspool\WebsocketBundle\Application\Application;
use Varspool\WebsocketBundle\Application\NamedApplication;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use  Krum\AGBundle\Controller\AGServicesController;


class ExempleApplication extends Application {

   protected $clients = array();


   public function onData($data, $client) {
      foreach ($this->clients as $sendto) {
         $scrutin = (json_decode($data) != NULL) ? true : false;
             if ($scrutin == true ){   
                 $vote = $scrutin["AGVote"];
                 $reponse = $scrutin["AFreponse"] ;
                 $users = $scrutin["users"];
             $scrutinservice = new AGServicesController();
             $scrutinsend = $controller->voteeffective($vote, $reponse, $users);

             $sendto->send($scrutinsend);
              }
            }
     else
        $sendto->send($data);

   }
 }
}
```

**My config.yml**

```
parameters:
    agservices.class:      Krum\AGBundle\Controller\AGServicesController

services :
  agservices:
    class : %agservices.class%
    arguments :
      container : "@service_container"
```

**services.yml**

**Edit 1 : sercices.yml configuration**

```
krum.agservices:
    class: Krum\AGBundle\Controller\AGServicesController    
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]
```

All answer is or idea is appreciable !

Thank you for watching ;)

**Edit 1 : Now, I have another ExceptionError

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Krum\AGBundle\Controller\AGServicesController::__construct(), called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Krum/src/Krum/AGBundle/Application/ExempleApplication.php on
>       line 62 and defined in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Krum/src/Krum/AGBundle/Controller/AGServicesController.php line 34
>   *

I thought that the services.yml should add in parameter automatically the correct doctrine entity manager or it just specify the type of the parameters and I have to add it manually while calling the controller ?

Comment: 1. You should provide the full exception stack trace.
2. Your service definition pass the service container as an argument to the controller's constructor, but you __construct does not have any argument.

Comment: Yep I have try it with put a parameters using the service.yml, but I not sure how its works, see below for more info ;)

Comment: Update of my post with news changes but still stuck :)